# WPF Chart with draggable points

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm searching for a WPF chart control which would let me drag points along the vertical axis, to change their values in real time.

Anyone know something that would do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to create your own custom chart control from scratch. Something may exist but your going to have to pay a pretty penny

[ComponentONE](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ChartWPF/) 
[Teleriks](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx) 
[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Overview)

Also im not 100% sure its customizable with drag and drops